# Как найти callback функцию recaptcha?

Tags: python, recaptcha

хочу написать авторегер на selenium но не могу решить капчу при регистрации. Там нет кнопки отправить токен, по документации надо найти callback функцию, вот у меня вопрос как её найти? (пытался но не смог) https://www.rambler.ru/

Answer (score 0):

Не во всех случаях `reCaptcha` использует callback функции. В данном случае Вам необходимо достать `google_key` - `6LeHeSkUAAAAANUvgxwQ6HOLXCT6w6jTtuJhpLU7`. После отправить запрос на решение каптчи и ответ вставить в поле

```
<textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid rgb(193, 193, 193); margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none; display: none;"></textarea>
```

Более подробная документация - [rucaptcha](https://rucaptcha.com/api-rucaptcha#solving_recaptchav2_new)

Comment: У меня была такая мысль, но... Кнопки на отправку капчи нету)

Comment: @ИльяВетров каптча отправляется при нажатии кнопки "Далее" с остальными данными